# Android load more content in table view

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, listview

I am new to android and studying. In one of the view, I am plotting contents from database ( server ) and dynamically creating a table view and showing listing as each row. ( ie shops list ).

Now I need to add a view more button at the bottom, ie initially plotting 50 shops names and shows the "view more" button at the end. When click need to add more TableRow from server.

But my questions are,

1. For fetching in database query, can I have the count of how many rows in that table ? So that I can pass that value to server and collect data from that number. Is it possible to get number of dynamically created table rows ?
2. As I am new to android, is this the safe way to do the same ? Other than fetching in the table view, is there any other easy view ?
3. If I created some tablerows already, can I append more rows to that after wards ?
4. There is any problem, performance issue if I add more ( say 1000 - 2500 ) rows by clicking "View More"

Please advice
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1.  getChildCount()
2. What you want to implement is earlier done through Button, now its Pull to refresh.
3. Yes of  course.
4. That can be handled, but its good to keep add more count lesser (but that depends upon size of each record).

Comment: thanks for your comment. On question 4th. I meant if I am adding 10 list on each "view more" and it got something around 2500 listing in page ( via 250 view more click ). Then is there is any chance for application crash ?

Comment: No, If you have coded in a good way i.e you need to take care of optimization+performance issues. You can check - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance